# How to bind to a private property?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a data grid where I need everything to have a fully scalable size.  I have no issue with the column headers, they all scale properly.  My issue is for the individual cells, they do not seem to respect their binding.

The binding for grid height seems to set the initial value fine, *but once the grid is displayed it does not change the height if the variable it is bound to changes.*

I had to subclass DataGridTextColumn to add some custom functionality.  I have a method called CreateDataGridColumn that returns a reference to ExtendedDataGridTextColumn.  These columns are then added to the data grid.  The data binding itself works fine, the grid shows all of the correct data.

Here is some code:

```
    private ExtendedDataGridTextColumn CreateDataGridColumn(EntityBase dataColumn, FormatConditionGroup formatConditionGroup)
    {
        ExtendedDataGridTextColumn newColumn = new ExtendedDataGridTextColumn(dataColumn);
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        String textBlockName = "Text" + dataColumn.EntityId;
        String columnTag = dataColumn.GetPropertyValue("Tag");

        // Create the TextBlock that will display the cell contents
        FrameworkElementFactory textBlockFNFactory;
        textBlockFNFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

        _gridTextHeightPercentage = dataColumn.GetPropertyDouble("GridFontSize", Constants.DefaultFontHeightPercent) / 2.8;
        _fontSize = GlobalVariables.DesignerPreviewHeight * (_gridTextHeightPercentage / 100);

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = _fontSize;
        textBlockFNFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, binding);

        // Do a whole bunch of stuff here

        // Create a border so that the label background does not obscure the grid lines
        FrameworkElementFactory borderFNFactory;
        borderFNFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
        borderFNFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFNFactory);

        // Add type to data template
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = borderFNFactory;

        newColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

        return newColumn;
    }
```

Then I have the following method fired on the SizeChanged event for the datagrid:

```
        _customDataGrid.TitleAreaHeight = new GridLength(GlobalVariables.DesignerPreviewHeight * (_titleHeightPercentage / 100));
        _customDataGrid.SetHeaderFontSize(GlobalVariables.DesignerPreviewHeight * (_headerHeightPercentage / 100));
        _fontSize = GlobalVariables.DesignerPreviewHeight * (_gridTextHeightPercentage / 100);
```

The first two lines do what they are supposed to, change the height of the title area which is something I added to my data grids and change the header height.  The update of the _fontSize variable though does not change the data grid cell text height.

Updated

As per suggestion I added a dependency property as such.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridFontHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GridFontHeight", typeof(double), typeof(CustomDataGrid));
```

Then changed my binding code to this.

```
        binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("GridFontHeight");
        textBlockFNFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, binding);
```

Then in my size changed added this.

```
        SetValue(GridFontHeightProperty, _fontSize);
```

But it does not work.  In this scenario it doesn't set the font height correctly to begin with, it just uses the default font height for the data grid.

Comment: I thought I was showing binding.  I create a binding object, set the source and then call SetBinding programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, no you can't bind to a private variable. My guess is, that your variable _fontSize is a `private double`, right? (See how i have to guess? ;))
You can bind to a public **property** or to a dependency property, which in your case fits well. So create a new dependency Property called FontSize and bind to that.

If for some reason you can't use a dependency property, you can still bind to normal CLR properties using [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) which should look something like

```
public double FontSize
{
    get{return _fontSize;}
    set
    {
        _fontSize = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FontSize"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what I tried, using a dependancy property, which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding correctly, nor can you do (strictly speaking) what you want.

Bindings are *always* against either ordinary code properties or against dependency properties. You cannot bind to fields. You could do something like this:

First, remove the `_fontSize` instance variable. You won't be using this anymore.

Next, define a `DependencyProperty` for this value:

```
    private const string FontSizePropertyName = "FontSize";
    private static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        FontSizePropertyName,
        typeof(double),
        typeof(ExtendedDataGridTextColumn),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    private double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then change your binding to this:

```
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = RelativeSource.Self;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath(FontSizeProperty)
    textBlockFNFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, binding);
```

Then just use your new `FontSize` property to set the value rather than updating a private field.

**Note:** You were close with your existing dependency property, but `PropertyPath` only takes a `string` if the property is a CLR (ordinary) property. For dependency properties, you should pass the actual `DependencyProperty` instance into it as shown above.

Comment: The line last parameter, new UIPropertyMetadata(0), causes an exception to be thrown, if I remove it no exception but it doesn't work.  It also really slows down the redraw for some reason.  Perhaps I need to send you a large sample with the actual classes in it.

Comment: @WPFNewbie: Try `0.0` rather than `0`.

Comment: Where is this code supposed to go?  Currently it is in my custom data grid class, which created the individual data columns.  I did try moving it all to the ExtendedDataGridTextColumn class, which made it very slow, like 10 seconds to render a data grid with 20 records in it, and it still didn't respect the binding.

Comment: @WPFNewbie: It should go wherever the `_fontSize` field was before. If that's not in `ExtendedDataGridTextColumn`, then the `typeof(ExtendedDataGridTextColumn)` in the code above should be `typeof(TypeWhereThePropertyIs)`.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to try and help me.  It is still not working.  It is not getting the font height at all, it is using the default font height.  BTW, the 0.0 did solve the other issue with an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I have couple of inputs on this...

1. Does your `ExtendedDataGridTextColumn` extend from `DataGridTextColumn` if so how come you are using `CellTemplate`? `DataGridTextColumn` has `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` to style TextBlock and TextBox represented by its cell.
2. If you are confident of your decision about `CellTemplate` in point 1 above then try....

   ```
     Binding binding = new Binding();
     binding.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
     binding.Source = _fontSize;
     textBlockFNFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, binding);
   ```

Let me know if any of these help.

Comment: +1 for BindsDirectlyToSource wasn't sure if it is the same or even possible as new Binding(".") and forgot about the property.

Comment: For you first question, yes it does extend it.  In my code for creating the ExtendedDataGridTextColumn I dynamically create several triggers.  These are configured in an XML file, but they may be as many of 20 triggers on a particular column.  I add these triggers to the DataTemplate object that I then assign to the CellTemplate.  If I could simplify this it would be great.

Comment: For the second answer, it didn't make a difference.  As dowhilefor pointed out, _fontSide is a private double declared in the class created the ExtendedDataGridTextColumn, not in the ExtendedDataGridTextColumn class itself.

Comment: I moved _fontSize to the ExtendedDataGridTextColumn class and that didn't work either.  Ultimately I would like to bind to a property set at the data grid level since in my implementation all cells will have the exact same text height and I would like to only have to update once variable/property to change it for all columns.